# I am currently using django 4.0 getting this error while including ('rest_auth.urls')

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-registration

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from Users.urls import * 
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include("Users.urls")),
    path('api/v1/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),

    ]
```

Error:-ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'

Comment: Could you add the `rest_auth.urls` code to the question?

Comment: The `django-rest-auth` project is no longer maintained, it says so in the projects README https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth#deprecated, it suggests using `dj-rest-auth` instead https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In rest_auth.urls do this:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
app_name = 'recipe'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
]
```

Hope your problem will solve now.